# Zero G overclocking

Tags: science-based

We overclockers love to push our systems for every bit of speed we can get. We  will resort to water cooling or building inside a beer fridge just to get a few more cycles.

So say one of us manages to get a chance to design a rotating space station. The habitat ring spins to maintain 1g. The center of the space station is at 0g. Our overclocker knows about the twin paradox. Can they expect a performance improvement by putting the computer at 0g and the humans at 1g? How much?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by the twin paradox? Are you asking how much time dilation there is in a slow-moving centrifuge?

Comment: About a few dozen Hertz per MHz; which will mostly get wasted in the lag from the extra long cables

Comment: @nzaman so it would help with long running processes, say contemplating the meaning of life, the universe, and everything, where lag is a trivial concern?

Comment: No. The increase is from the perspective of the observer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you know that red cars go faster than (say) blue cars?

I'm not kidding. There was some research done on this about 20 years ago, and in theoretical terms, the light being absorbed v. the light being reflected off red cars makes them able to travel just that little bit faster than blue cars.

How much faster? Truth be told, it's not measurable. It's WAY too small an improvement to be useful or even measurable.

Good story, I know. But for your overclocker, even if relativity works that way, the difference isn't going to be measurable. To maintain 1G of gravity on a habitable ring, by definition you can only be spinning so fast, and there would be no measurable relativistic effects in this case.

What you COULD do though is build a space station that is effectively a long tube, with the computers at one end and the humans at the other, in a tidally locked orbit around a black hole. The tidal lock would have the humans closest to the black hole, and the computers further out. In that context, the results of computer processing would APPEAR to be much faster to the humans subjectively, but given that the outcomes would likely be relevant to an external environment, it wouldn't actually help.

BUT, for lan parties, this would be the coolest possible quake server configuration you could possibly imagine.

Comment: "Time flies when you're having fun - in a slightly more literal sense than usual, thanks to our newest black hole powered game centers"

Answer (score 0):

Your 1g vs 0g situation does not give any time dilation at all.  You feel gravity because of acceleration, not bent space, so no time dilation from gravity.

You might be able to measure time dilation from speed.  If your ring has about 225  meter radius and spins at 2 rotations per minute, then you get 1g and your edge will be going almost 50 meters per second relative to the center.  That's more than 100 miles per hour.  1.5x10^-7 times the speed of light.  That will give you a time dilation of ... sorry my calculator doesn't have enough decimal places to display a number that small.  It's less than 1 part in a 10 billion.  Which means you wont even get a single cycle per second increase on a 4GHz machine.

You'd have to get humans on the edge going *much* faster for there to be a difference.

Check out this [time dilation calculator](http://www.emc2-explained.info/Dilation-Calc/#.WqOcG-jwaUk)
and this [ring station calculator](https://www.artificial-gravity.com/sw/SpinCalc/)

to play with some other ring sizes and speeds.